# How to show custom meta_key in each li of menu

Tags: theme-development, theme-options

I created a field in category section which is category color.
**Codes are in different lines in file so I will paste them separately**

```
$kategoriler_self = get_categories(array( 'hide_empty' => false ));
foreach ($kategoriler_self as $kategori){
$this->kategoriler[$kategori->cat_ID] = $kategori->cat_name;
```

*

```
$kategoriid = $kategori;
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=' .$kategoriid. '&posts_per_page=1' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
```

*

```
/* Cat Color Option */
$color = get_term_meta( $kategoriid, '_category_color', true );
$color = ( ! empty( $color ) ) ? "#{$color}" : '#000';
```

And I show my category color with this code

```
<?php echo $color;  ?>
```

**So, I want to do same thing for my menu.**
Here is my menu codes.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'sidebar-kategori', 'container' => 'false', 'items_wrap' => '<ul>%3$s</ul>')); ?>
```

**How can I show category color for every li in menu ?**

Thank you for reading it!

### **UPDATE:**

I found a nice article about my question and I want to share.

https://digwp.com/2011/11/html-formatting-custom-menus/

Answer (score 0):

You can `add_filter()` the [`wp_nav_menu_items()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/) hook. It gives access to the html output of the list items with `$items`.

Immediately after this hook is `wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items()` hook that gives you access to the same but for a specific menu.

[Info on `add-filter()` if you need it.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/)

The two `wp_nav_menu_items` related hooks in context:

[They are at lines 220 and 231 of `wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L220)
From trac:

```
/**
211          * Filters the HTML list content for navigation menus.
212          *
213          * @since 3.0.0
214          *
215          * @see wp_nav_menu()
216          *
217          * @param string   $items The HTML list content for the menu items.
218          * @param stdClass $args  An object containing wp_nav_menu() arguments.
219          */
220         $items = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_items', $items, $args );
221         /**
222          * Filters the HTML list content for a specific navigation menu.
223          *
224          * @since 3.0.0
225          *
226          * @see wp_nav_menu()
227          *
228          * @param string   $items The HTML list content for the menu items.
229          * @param stdClass $args  An object containing wp_nav_menu() arguments.
230          */
231         $items = apply_filters( "wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items", $items, $args );
```